# Формат пикселей для текстуры с одним цветовым каналом OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, текстура

Имею текстуру отражения (Specular Map), использую её в шейдере подобным образом:

```
vec3 specular = texture(specularMap, fs_in.TexCoords).rgb * spec;
```

Всё работает нормально, блик там, где нужно, но красного цвета.
Почему красного - понимаю, из-за определения такого формата пикселей для текстуры, когда всего 1 байт на пиксель:

```
SDL_Surface* data = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
...
auto nrComponents = static_cast<uint16_t>(data->format->BytesPerPixel);
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;
...
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, data->w, data->h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data->pixels);
```

Я не понимаю, какой формат нужно установить...Что только не пробовал, блика либо нет вообще, либо он есть и красный, если GL_RED.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вы в шейдере вытащите R значение пикселя и из него сделайте новое RGB значение, все элементы которого будут равны этому вытащенному R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так в шейдере напишите, чтобы красный канал одинаково шёл все три RGB компоненты вашего белого блика:

```
vec3 specular = texture(specularMap, fs_in.TexCoords).rrr * spec;
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое, дружище, второй раз уже помогаешь)))

Comment: @ГлебТруфанов не вопрос - будут еще хорошо сформулированные вопросы - задавай! )